# Enviar datos Drag and Drop de un Grid a otro

Tags: c#, windows-forms, gridview, drag-and-drop

En mi proyecto me surgió la siguiente duda:

- Tengo 2 `dataGridView`, donde al `dataGridView1` sería una lista de productos  (una consulta `SQL` de productos).
- Me gustaría saber si puedo arrastrar de este `dataGridView1` y soltar al `dataGridView2` que sería la compra que el cliente se está llevando y poder guardar esta otra información como factura #xxx.

estoy intentando con este codigo y no se envia el item, ¿que será?

```
   using Npgsql;
         namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
    public event DragEventHandler DragDrop;
    private DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {



            string connstring = String.Format("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=123;Database=BDsystem");

            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM simple_table";

            NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

            ds.Reset();

            da.Fill(ds);

            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(msg.ToString());
            throw;

        }
    }
    private void MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        if (hitTestInfo.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(hitTestInfo.RowIndex,
                DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
        }

    }
    private void dataGridView2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat) ? DragDropEffects.Copy : DragDropEffects.None;
    }
    private void dataGridView2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string dropData = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(dropData);

        var cells = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                        .Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
        dataGridView2.Rows.Add(cells);

        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Si, lo que dices el posible. Primero, en el dataGridView2 tienes que poner la propiedad `AllowDrop` a true. Luego te suscribes al evento `DragDrop` del dataGridView2 donde recibiras los datos a mover en `e.Data`. Por ultimo, tendrás que manualmente eliminar las filas del dataGridview1 y añadirlas al dataGridView2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ademas de finirnir la propiedad `AllowDrop = true` deberas usar algunos evento para ejecutar el movimiento de las filas entre grids

Los eventos son `DragEnter` y [DragDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dragdrop.aspx)

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitTestInfo = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hitTestInfo.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(hitTestInfo.RowIndex,
            DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
}

private void dataGridView2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat) ? DragDropEffects.Copy : DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void dataGridView2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string dropData = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
    int rowIndex = int.Parse(dropData);

    var cells = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                    .Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add(cells);

    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
}
```

la idea es pasar el index de la row de un grid al otro cuando se produce el evento de drag drop

[Select and drag a datagridview row with a single click](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/16b0a44e-35a0-4bc8-9ccd-ec2c62c95a55/select-and-drag-a-datagridview-row-with-a-single-click?forum=winforms)

[Arrastrar fila desde un datagridview a otro datagridview](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/fa33fe4d-a729-42bb-996d-81f045094aa8/arrastrar-fila-desde-un-datagridview-a-otro-datagridview?forum=vcses)

Comment: Disculpe, Sr @leandro-tuttini podria revisar mi edicion de la pregunta en lo que pueda? se lo agradeceria mucho