# reportes c# y postrgres

Tags: c#, visual-studio, postgresql, reportviewer

buenas noches de antemano muchas gracias por cualquier aporte, me encuentro realizando un proyecto y a la hora de hacer los reporte me tropiezo con `Npgsql` no lo se enlazar con el `ReportViewer` alguna sugerencia? o quiza un editor de reportes defirentes al de VS como report manager pero igual conectarlo con `Npgsql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que no necesitas enlazar nada de Npgsql contra ReportViewer

Si has creado un reporte local .rdlc debes vincular este a un origen de datos, pudiendo ser un datatable o lista basada en el tipo que definas.

Este ejemplo

[How to create local reports RDLC featuring barcode images in ASP.NET](http://neodynamic.com/ND/FaqsTipsTricks.aspx?tabid=66&prodid=1&sid=66)

esta muy completo.
Alli veras que puedes conectar el reporte a un dataset o a un Custom Objects

La idea es que uses ado.net de forma tradicional con las librerias de Npgsql para cargar el objeto que luego asignarias al reporte para vincularlo a datos

Comment: Buenas noches, muchas gracias por todo de verdad, discuple la cuestión sera que se da una pasada por esta pregunta en lo que pueda [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26920/enviar-datos-drag-and-drop-de-un-grid-a-otro] la edite y lo mencione pero creo que no lo supe mensionar..  de cualquier forma muchas gracias